# Google Map API loads the alert again and again

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-chrome

when using google maps api on my webpage the user is asked on alert that the "webpage want to know the location".Once the user selects allow and reloading the page where the call for google maps api is running ,the page does not show the alert box  second time onwards.But in some system in chrome browser the user is asked for location on every page loads

image is below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLzM8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In your function/code make sure to add `return;` at the end of the code requesting location access.

Comment: My code: $.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + loc.coords.latitude + ',' + loc.coords.longitude + '&key=' + domElements.mapsApiKey)
        .then(_mapsSuccessCallback, _mapsErrorCallback);//Should i add it here return; or after the successCallBack.Also how would this stop asking the alert on next load because the call for API goes